# Scaffold Identity that users int instead of string as primary keys in .Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the simplest way to scaffold a .Net Core 2.1 project from scratch to use int instead of string as primary key for the ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole classes?

Steps I have taken so far are:

1. Create New Web Application
2. Change Authentication to Individual User Accounts
3. Create Application User Class:

   `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>`
4. Create ApplicationRole Class:

   `public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the below steps :

1. Create new application with `Individual User Accounts` authentication template .
2. Update the `ApplicationDbContext` class to derive from `IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey>`. Specify the new key type for `TKey` :

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext
         : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>, int>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. `Startup.ConfigureServices` must be updated to use the generic user:

   ```
   services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>>()
       .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>>()
       .AddDefaultUI()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   ```
4. Modify the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` to use the generic user :

   ```
   @inject SignInManager<IdentityUser<int>> SignInManager
   @inject UserManager<IdentityUser<int>> UserManager
   ```
5. If the database was created before the PK change, run `Drop-Database` (PMC) or `dotnet ef database drop` (.NET Core CLI) to delete it. After confirming deletion of the database, remove the initial migration with `Remove-Migration` (PMC) or `dotnet ef migrations remove` (.NET Core CLI).
6. At last , seed the database  : `Add-Migration MigrationName` and `Update-Database` in PMC .

Comment: This works great! - but how would I use do it with an ApplicationUser class that inherits from IdentityUser<int> and also contains the property "FirstName" - When I do this and try to register with FirstName included,  I'm getting an error saying `    Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` when I try to do this

Comment: @RoddyBalkan , replace `IdentityUser<int>`  with `ApplicationUser <int>` in ApplicationDbContext ,ConfigureServices  and _LoginPartial